# Angular module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to write an angular app using best code practice and i got to this:

index.html file contain :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app='hrsApp'>
 <head>
<title>Hrs app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<div class='container'>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
<script src='js/controllers/homeCtrl.js'></script>
<script src='js/controllers/avCtrl.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main file: app.js:

```
angular.module('home', []);
angular.module('av', []);

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('hrsApp', [
'hrsApp.controllers',
'hrsApp.services',
'hrsApp.directives',
'hrsApp.filters',

// AngularJS
'ngRoute',

// All modules are being loaded here but EMPTY - they will be filled with controllers and      functionality
'home',
'av'
]);

// configure our routes
angular.module('hrsApp').config([
'$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';

    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/av', {
            templateUrl: 'views/av.html',
            controller: 'avCtrl'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
]);
```

Then i added the home controller:

```
/*global angular*/

angular.module('home').controller('homeCtrl', [
 '$scope',
function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope._init = function () {
        $scope.message = "welcome to Home Ctrl";
    };

    // DESTRUCTOR
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

    });

    // Run constructor
    $scope._init();

    $scope.log('info', '[HomeCtrl] initialized');
}
]);
```

and home template that for the moment contain only a binding to the message variable:

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

When i try to run the application i got : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=hrsApp&p1=Error%3A%…googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3) angular.js:38

Any idea what i do wrong?

Comment: Can you put the full error URL? (open on the browser and then ctrlc ctrlv)

Comment: just include `app.js` after `homeCtrl.js` and `avCtrl.js`

Comment: where you define next modules: `'hrsApp.controllers',
'hrsApp.services',
'hrsApp.directives',
'hrsApp.filters'`

Comment: i did include app.js after homeCtrl and i got 3 errors injector.nomod ... i didn't created yet services directive, filter but even if i commenyt them i still got initial p[roblem ...

Comment: i see i think you're right they are not defined .. but how i should define them and where? This was the fix .. how may i vote your answer?

Comment: something like `angular.module('hrsApp.controllers',[]); angular.module('hrsApp.services',[]); angular.module('hrsApp.directives',[]); angular.module('hrsApp.filters',[]);`

Comment: i declared them before angular.module('hrsApp', [ and is working ...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From your code I can see that you have injected modules that you did not declared.

in order todo so you must add the following lines to your code:

```
angular.module('hrsApp.controllers',[]);
angular.module('hrsApp.services',[]);
angular.module('hrsApp.directives',[]);
angular.module('hrsApp.filters',[]);
```

Comment: you are right thanks but seems unethical to vote your question when @Grundy already give the right answer before you.